# Как обратиться к объекту из класса Screen, находясь в классе App?

Tags: python, kivy

Я хочу выбрать объект из класса `Screen`, находясь в классе App.

Я заштриховал команду в коде что я хочу.

`main.py`:

```
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.lang import Builder
    from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

    class Screeen(Screen):
        pass

    class Manager(ScreenManager):
        pass

    kv = Builder.load_file("plann.kv")
    class Ball(App):
        #def on_stop(self):
            #print(Screeen.ids.textinput.text)

        def build(self):
            return kv

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        Ball().run()
```

`plann.kv`:

```
    Manager:
        Screeen:
    
    <Screeen>:
        name: "Screeen"
        textinput: textinput
        FloatLayout:
            size: root.width, root.height
            TextInput:
                id: textinput
                text: "hi"
                size_hint: (.45, .1)
                pos: root.width * 1 / 3 , root.height * 1 / 2
```

Comment: переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык